# Need advice to get my logic correct in d7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

**Goal:** Is to save information of a node which gets updated. We need to gather the node id of the node which is updated and also the user names of people who have bookmarked it.

**Implementation:**

I have managed to get the both this detail using flags and rules module. I made a custom module which implemented the hook to get this info.

**I am getting stuck here:**

Now  I need to save the user name and the node id. I am still deciding if I want to use fields or the db layer.

One username can have multiple node id saved.

Now the problem is I don't know for sure how many nodes will be enough. It depends on the user. It can be 5 can be 500 or even 5000 node ids that might  need to be saved for one user.

**So how do I make provision for this ?**

So I am stuck with the logic. How should I use the db layer or the fields in custom content type to save this ? and how should I do it ?

Please advice. I am using d7.

## custom module code

```
/*
* Implementation of the hook_rules_action_info() 
* 
*/
function customvishal_rules_action_info()
{
$actions = array(
'customvishal_action_userdetail' => array(
    'label' =>t('Custom function to send notifications'),
    'group'=>t('Cusotm Code for sending notifications'),
    'parameter'=> array(
     'account'=> array(
         'type'=>'user',
         'label'=>t('Going to get user list'),
         
     ),
      
     // for the node
     'productdetail'=> array(
         'type'=>'node',
         'label'=>t('Passding the node data'),
         
     ),   
        
        
        
    )
 ),



 ); 

 return $actions; 

 }


/*
* The action function for the rules exampled hello world
* 
*/
function customvishal_action_userdetail($account,$productdetail)
{

 drupal_set_message(t('This user #username! has flagged it', 
      array('#username' => $account->mail)));

 drupal_set_message(t('This node #nid has got updated', 
      array('#nid' => $productdetail->nid)));


 // The above takes care of the node and the user information later I will put 
 // it in a db or  something like  that.
      

 // end of the function customvishal_action_userdetail
 }
```

Comment: So as I understand, you would like to link a username with various node IDs? Is it the person that created the node that gets linked with it or any person? Can you describe the problem a little bit more in-depth or possibly provide the code which you have already written?

Comment: @kerrM: any person can be linked to a node . I am using the flag module so that a person can bookmark the node. I have edited my question for more info. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really seems like you should be using [hook_node_update()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7) and [hook_node_insert()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) to for access to nodes that have just been added or updated.

If you wanted access to the node data just before it was saved, then [hook_node_presave()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) would be the one to use.

I don't think you need presave though because you mentioned you needed the node ID, and presave does not have that for new nodes yet.

Here's a way to process new and updated nodes.  The first 2 functions just hook into the right place and route the node to the 3rd function.

```
<?php
// hook into node inserts
function customvishal_node_insert($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'mynodetype') {
    customvishal_handle_data($node);
  }
}

// hook into node updates
function customvishal_node_update($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'mynodetype') {
    customvishal_handle_data($node);
  }

}

// custom handler for the nodes
function customvishal_handle_data($node) {
  // load a user object of the node's author
  $author = user_load($node->uid);

  // now do what we need to do with $node and $user data

}
```

Remember you need to clear the Drupal cache for new hooks in your module to work in D7.